# hibernate joined subclassess duplicate key

Tags: hibernate, joined-subclass

thank you for you curiosity, I need you help :).

So, I created a joined inheritance: the parent class is called 'Action', and the subclasses are called 'AwardAction' and 'LevelUpAction'. I created the 3 classes with the hibernate annotations and the 3 tables. It worked fine for several month but a problem occurs recently.

The problem is that we find out two entries 'LevelUpAction' and 'AwardAction' with the same id, related to one entry in 'Action' ! 
     [  Action id=502  ] 
    /                   \ 
   /                     \ 
[AwardAction id=502]      [LevelUpAction id=502]

this case shouldn't occurs. Each levelUpAction and AwardAction should have its own id...

We check the code, but didn't find any problem. Actually no AwardAction should have been created in this case. We think that a LevelUpAction entry has been created (as expected) and that hibernate (for a unknown reason) created an AwardAction entry as well.

Actually I would like to get your point of view regarding the tables and the classes please.

Classes:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Action extends AbstractKeyEntity {

@Column
@NotEmpty
private String userKey;

@Column
@NotNull
private int points = 0;

protected Action() {
}

protected Action(String userKey, int points) {
    super();
    this.userKey = userKey;
    this.points = points;
}

public int getPoints() {
    return points;
}

public String getUserKey(){
    return userKey;
}
}
```

---

```
@Entity
public class AwardAction extends Action {
@ForeignKey(name = "fk_achievement_award_action_to_award")
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "badge_id")
@NotNull
private Badge badge;

public Badge getBadge() {
    return badge;
}

AwardAction() {

}

AwardAction(String userKey, int points, Badge badge) {
    super(userKey, points);
    this.badge = badge;
}
}
```

---

```
@Entity
public class LevelUpAction extends Action {

@ForeignKey(name = "fk_achievement_level_up_action_achievement_level")
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "achievement_level_id")
@NotNull
private AchievementLevel achievementLevel;

@Column(columnDefinition = "BIT", length = 1)
@NotNull
private boolean fast = false;

@Column(columnDefinition = "BIT", length = 1)
@NotNull
private boolean rich = false;

@Column
private Long fastDuration = 0L;

@Column
private Long richPoints = 0L;

public LevelUpAction() {

}

public LevelUpAction(String userKey, int points, AchievementLevel achievementLevel) {
    super(userKey, points);
    this.achievementLevel = achievementLevel;
}

public boolean isFast() {
    return fast;
}

public void setFast(boolean fast) {
    this.fast = fast;
}

public boolean isRich() {
    return rich;
}

public void setRich(boolean rich) {
    this.rich = rich;
}

public Long getFastDuration() {
    return fastDuration;
}

public void setFastDuration(Long fastDuration) {
    this.fastDuration = fastDuration;
}

public Long getRichPoints() {
    return richPoints;
}

public void setRichPoints(Long richPoints) {
    this.richPoints = richPoints;
}

}
```

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `level_up_action` (
`fast` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
`fast_duration` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`rich` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
`rich_points` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`achievement_level_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `fk_achievement_level_up_action_achievement_level` (`achievement_level_id`),
KEY `FK_achievement_level_up_action_to_achievement_action` (`id`),
CONSTRAINT `fk_achievement_level_up_action_achievement_level` FOREIGN KEY     (`achievement_level_id`) REFERENCES `achievement_level` (`id`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_achievement_level_up_action_to_action` FOREIGN KEY (`id`)     REFERENCES `action` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE `action` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `created_by` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `entity_key` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `modified_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified_by` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `rs_deleted` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `version` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `points` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_key` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_action_entity_key` (`entity_key`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=507 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE `award_action` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `badge_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_award_action_to_badge` (`badge_id`),
  KEY `FK_award_action_to_achievement_action` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_award_action_to_badge` FOREIGN KEY (`badge_id`) REFERENCES `badge` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_award_action_to_action` FOREIGN KEY (`id`)         REFERENCES `action` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```